# 22.04 when upgrading the server can not make outgoing connections neither receive from vpn

Tags: networking, server, upgrade, lan

After the last upgrading of a 20.04 LTS server, can not perform outgoing connections but yes incoming ones.

I mean: from the LAN I can ping the server. But the server can't ping neither machines in the LAN (nor WAN).

In fact, when upgrading the system started to report problems accessing repositories.
Is not possible to access the server from the VPN. (site to site VPN at the sonicwall).

The command IP route gives the correct gateway

Any idea?